# Model in Model View Controller

Tags: visualforce-component

I came across multiple choice for sample exam But was not sure whether  Custom Component comes under Model in MVC ? Choose two

Options were

1. Custom Object
2. Custom Component
3. Apex
4. Controller Extension

Answer (score 8):

The correct answers are **Custom Object** and **Apex**, assuming that by Apex the writer behind the question meant the [Apex properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) inside controllers and extensions.

I won't bore you with [what you can already find on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) about MVC, so on to Salesforce!

- Visualforce pages and components are **views**
- Apex controllers and extensions are all considered **controllers**
- Your `Sobject` classes (e.g., `OpportunityLineItem`, `AccountTeamMember`) are the **models**. A model represents all the data transmitted between the page/component and the controller/extensions via properties.

Comment: This doesn't really line up with the question, but that's more a reflection of the sample exams out there and why they should be avoided.

Comment: Good call. I'll edit the answer to more directly answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that Custom Object and Custom Component are the correct answers. 
Apex and Controller Extension are Controllers.